# How to sort an List of List type?

Tags: java

```
List<List> d=new Arraylist<List>();
```

How can I sort the list `d`? If I use `Collection.sort(d);` I receive the following error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not
applicable for the arguments (List<List>). The inferred type List is not a
valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: It should be Collections.sort(d) shouldnt it? With an s

Comment: Well, is `List` comparable? ---No, it isn't. You must decide on the sort criterion and supply te appropriate comparator.

Comment: How do you compare two lists?

Answer (score 5):

You have a list of lists. The inner list cannot be sorted as [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) does not know how to. You can do this if you want

```
Collections.sort (d, new Comparator(){...});
```

Then the comparator you pass in will work out how to sort the list.

For example the comparator could be assuming

```
new Comparator<List>(){
       public int compare(List l1,List l2){
            //write appropriate checks and comparisons here
            return l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0);
       }}
```

I think you should think about what you want to do here though. If you haev a list and then each element itself is a list do you really want to sort it? Sort by what?

Comment: I see list length as a nice candidate. Also, lexicographic order would be a useful choice (sorting by first element, breaking ties with the second element, and so on).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik +1 for teaching me that lexicographic order is for arbitrary types that can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parametrize your `List` with types that implement `Comparable`.

`List` is not a `Comparable` type.

Thinking back: what criteria would you use to sort your `List`s?

Comment: If OP wanst to sort a list of lists, he hardly has the choice to change te type parameter. What he should actually do is supply a custom comparator.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree and disagree. I suspect the idea of sorting `List`s in the first place might come from a strategy that could be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [API for the sort Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) it states:

> All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface.

You need to change your `List` to implement Comparable or you need to use a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in the phase where change is possible, you could always build your own implementation of list, that is, make a class that implements both the `List` interface and the `Comparable` interface.

It would be up to you then, to define a proper comparator.

```
public class MyList implements List<Whatever>, Comparable<MyList>
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyList otherList) { }
    // override all the other methods from the List interface
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<MyList> d = new Arraylist<MyList>();
Collections.sort(d);
```